# Convert SRE_Match object to string

Tags: python, regex

The output of my `re.search` returns `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10d6ed4e0>` I was wondering how could I convert this to a string? or a more readable form?

Comment: `re.search()` tells you whether the regex matches the string.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should do it as:

```
result = re.search(your_stuff_here)
if result:
    print result.group(0)
```

Comment: @sshashank124 actually the group parameter must be index of the group which matched.

E.g. if the regex is "abc(def)" and it matches, we will have "abcdef" at index 0 and "def" at index 1

Comment: `result.group(0)` works only if you dont have capture groups in parentheses. Otherwise you should be doing `result.group()`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to see all groups in order:

```
result = re.search(your_stuff_here)
if result:
    print result.groups()
```