# Python script for MySql prints out SRE_Match object at 0x7f79ce81b440> lines, how can I get it to print actual query results?

Tags: python, mysql

I am running a search for latitude/ longitude coordinates in messages in a table , acars. , Directional char combos such as N or NW followed by 5 digits, The script runs, however it just gives me lines like this:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f79ce81b440>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f79ce81b440>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f79ce81b440>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f79ce81b440>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f79ce81b440>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f79ce81b440>
```

I want to see the results of my script (the latitude/longitudes), I've tried [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025565/convert-sre-match-object-to-string) and all of them resulted in the terminal just pausing forever when I try to execute the code. Also [I tried the suggestion for .search() from here](https://howchoo.com/g/zdvmogrlngz/python-regexes-findall-search-and-match)   with the same result. Tried the Findall option from there and got endless lines of PBI D024

I'm using a Unix based VM (ScotchBox) to run mysql on terminal in that enviroment, Windows 10 PC

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# from: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql-query

import mysql.connector
import re
import datetime

# Open connection.  My database is named planes.  If you named yours something else
# then change the database= here. 
db = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='planes',user='root',password='root')

# prepare a cursor "SELECT * from planes.acars limit 10")
cursor = db.cursor ( )

# Do the query -- the limit is just to keep this small, you will not need it

query = ("SELECT msg_text FROM acars "
"WHERE date_time_stamp BETWEEN %s AND %s")
first_of_june = datetime.date(2016, 6,1)
last_of_june = datetime.date(2016, 6,30)
cursor.execute(query, (first_of_june, last_of_june))
# Fetch rows
data = cursor.fetchone ( )
while data is not None:
    coordinates = re.compile ("N|NW|S|SW|E|NE|S|SE^[0-9]{5}")
    print(coordinates.search(str(data)))
    data = cursor.fetchone()

# close cursor
cursor.close ( )

# close connection
db.close ( )
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: `print(coordinates.search(str(data)).group(0))` it should work i guess

Answer (score 0):

"SRE_Match object" means the search query has got a successful search pattern hit.

We can print all the matched results using sre_match_object.groups()

Re-writing the while loop snipped with the printable version of search results:

```
while data is not None:
    coordinates = re.compile ("N|NW|S|SW|E|NE|S|SE^[0-9]{5}")
    match_obj = coordinates.search(str(data))
    if match_obj:
        print(match_obj.groups())
    data = cursor.fetchone()
```

-Ram

Comment: All I get with this is a lot of ()

Comment: To get rid of () from the print statement, please use print(match_obj.groups()[0]) instead of print(match_obj.groups()).

Actually match_obj.groups() returns the set of matched items. So above command prints the first item from the matched entries.