# float() argument must be a string or a number, not '_sre.SRE_Match'

Tags: python, regex, object, floating-point

I'm writing some code to get raw HTML from a site, pinpoint a certain value which might change over time using regex and compare it with a value stored in a text file.

Everything works, apart from converting my regex object into a floating point number to allow comparison with another floating point number.

```py
    def find_new_value(): # retrieves value from website
        cmc_html = requests.get('https://websitewithvalue.com')
        noStarchSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(cmc_html.text, 
        features="html.parser")
        return noStarchSoup   

   new_value = float(btc_regex2.search(str(find_new_value())))
```

leads to - 
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not '_sre.SRE_Match'

```
    print(new_value)
```

prints:
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(77, 85), match='10191.53'>

I want to use match='10191.53' from the object to perform arithmetic with it. How can I pick this value out from the object?

I've read the regex documentation and tried a number of different combinations of str() int() and float() functions to manipulate the object's value into eventually being float.

I can understand why float() can't be used on this, but not how to get the 10191.53 value from the object to use it in mathematical operations.

Comment: you need to extract the group I would assume. It would help if you included the imports as well.

Comment: `search = btc_regex2.search(str(find_new_value())); new_value = float(search.group(0)) if search else 0` - theoretically the object can be None (if there wasn't any match), so you should save your search result and see whether it's empty or not. Also improved readability a bit.

Comment: Thanks, QHarr! That answered my question and got the outcome I wanted. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pattern matches exactly the string you want to convert to a float, you can call

```
result = regex.search(value)
new_value_str = result.group(0)
new_value = float(new_value_str)
```

to return the resulting match from your search as a string and convert it to a float ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group)). m.group(0) returns the entire match as a string. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025565/convert-sre-match-object-to-string).

Answer (score 2):

As people have pointed out in the comments, you need to extract the captured group using

```
new_value.groups()
```

The output of this method depends on the syntax of your regular expression. In order for `groups` to work, you need to have *capturing groups* in you regular expression, otherwise `groups` will always be empty even if the expression was a match to the input.

**TLDR**;

Make sure your expression is capturing the text that you want, and extract it from the match using the method `groups`.